# AWS Textract OCR reading PDF as single line instead of preserving line breaks

Tags: pdf, ocr, text-processing, amazon-textract

Hi I am new to AWS Textract.

[image: Input Pdf file]

I am using Amazon Textract to extract text from a PDF file. However, the output is not preserving the line breaks from the original PDF.

For example, in the PDF there are separate lines like:

Seller

Buyer

But in the Textract output, it is reading it as:
**Seller: Buyer:**

Instead of separate lines, the text is concatenated into a single string.
[image]

I would like Textract to retain the line breaks and structure from the original PDF. The lines denote different sections so I need to preserve that formatting.

Is there any way to configure Textract to output multi-line strings instead of concatenating everything into a single line? Or does it require post-processing the Textract result to split it based on the line breaks?

Any suggestions on how to properly extract text from a PDF while keeping the original line structure would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, as Textract just released a new feature which might be helpful to your use case specifically.

[Amazon Textract launches Layout feature to extract paragraphs, titles, and more from documents](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/09/amazon-textract-layout-feature-extract-paragraphs-titles-documents/)

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I will definitely try this and update you.

Comment: This is superb @Rohan. Thanks a lot for this information. Really going to change my NLP process. I had hard time dealing with getting properly ocr result. but This AWS textract Layout is giving me exact result what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: Sounds great! Glad the new offering is able to help greatly simplify the NLP process now!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `amazon-textract-textractor` package to interact with Amazon Textract.

For example you can extract the text like this

```py
from textractor import Textractor
from textractor.data.constants import TextractFeatures
extractor = Textractor(profile_name="default")
document = extractor.detect_document_text(
    file_source="./gvE4G.png",
)
```

Access the individual lines here

```py
document.lines
```

And this is what you get on your redacted document.

```
[-,
 DATE,
 28-Oct-22,
 BC#,
 2810,
 confirms@,
 BUYER,
 SELLER,
 ties LLC,
 ing LLC,
 Denis Garcia,
 Hugh Murtha,
 h,
 ura.com,
 point.com,
 3050 Post Oak Bvld,
 5 Houston Center1401 McKinney Suite 1500,
 Houston,
 Houston,
 TX, 77098,
 TX, 77056]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `start_document_analysis` to extract the content as per the pdf.  You can use `TABLE` to extract the data from each section. The approch can be different to each pdf  based on how it got created.

This video gives a generic source code. You just need to replace with your pdf path.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNnFfTZsmjc

Source code: https://github.com/CodeSam621/Demo/tree/main/TextractAsync